# ionic app: unable to delete item when item-icon-right class is set

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a simple ionic list created using

```
    <ion-list style="font-size:small;"
              ng-class-odd="'odd-row'"
              ng-class-even="'even-row'"
              can-swipe="true">
        <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-class="(state.added === true)? 'item-icon-right' : ''" ng-repeat="state in getOperatingStates() | filter:filterSelectedItems">
                {{state.StateName}}
            <i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline" ng-if="state.added === true"></i>
            <ion-option-button class="button-assertive icon ion-trash-a" ng-click="removeOperation(state)"></ion-option-button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

I am basically trying to show an indication to the user that some of the items are newly added before saving it.

I am able to swipe and see the delete button and delete the item normally, but when a new item is added i.e. a flag `state.added` flag is set on the item, I can't get the swipe button to stick on once i swipe the item.

**EDIT 1:**

I see that if I apply the just applying the class `item-icon-right` or `item-icon-left` the swipe functionality breaks.

can some one please explain me what I may be doing wrong there?

Comment: Have you already tried to pass the added property to all items in the list? Like all already added states(added: false) and new ones(added:true). And what do you mean by "I can't get the swipe button to stick on...", can you see a button after a swipe?

Comment: @Blauharley : Yes, the AngularJS is all properly setup with whatever binding I am using, its just that somehow looks to me that when there are items with icons on the left, I see this issue in ionic framework. Also i see no error on the console.